# Indexing taking long time when using openNLP Lemmatizer with Solr

Tags: solr, lucene, opennlp, lemmatization

I am trying to integrate openNLP with Solr.
I completed the integration for openNLP lemmatization,but while indexing the documents take long time to complete indexing(also commit).

**schema**:

Does the opennlp_text field be indexed="true"?

```
<fieldType name="open_nlp" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.OpenNLPTokenizerFactory" sentenceModel="opennlp/en-sent.bin"  tokenizerModel="opennlp/en-token.bin"/>
    <filter class="solr.OpenNLPFilterFactory" posTaggerModel="opennlp/en-pos-maxent.bin"/>
   <filter class="solr.OpenNLPLemmatizerFilterFactory" dictionary="opennlp/en-lemmatizer.txt"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

en-lemmatizer.txt->The file has a size of 7mb.

**The indexing time prior to lemmatizer implementation was 2 to 3mts,but now it is ~2hrs for the same documents**.I have no idea why such time difference occurred during indexing.When I analyzed the field I couldn't find the result too for lemmatization.Kindly help me in writing an effective structure so that the indexing performance is faster and good also it will be helpful to know the best implementation for the same.

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: may be it's just opennlp which doing lemmatizer slowly?

Comment: I was unable to get the desired output from the field when tried to analyze it from solr admin UI.I am not getting whats going wrong.

Comment: could you try to run lemmatizer alone for your documents, without indexing and see, how long it will take

Comment: do i need to remove these from the analyzer :<tokenizer class="solr.OpenNLPTokenizerFactory" sentenceModel="opennlp/en-sent.bin"  tokenizerModel="opennlp/en-token.bin"/>
    <filter class="solr.OpenNLPFilterFactory" posTaggerModel="opennlp/en-pos-maxent.bin"/> and do i need to remove index=true from the field?